# Pinescript I want to know when my line is over and under the candles

Tags: variables, plot, pine-script, offset

I'm new to pinescript and i want to know how to get 2 variables when my line "Chikou" is over and under the candles.

my code:

```
study(title="Chikou", shorttitle="Chikou", overlay = true)
displacement = input(17, minval=1)
xChikou = close
Chikou = plot(xChikou, color= white , title="Chikou", offset = -displacement)
```

I want something like that:

```
ChikouOver = Chikou > close
ChikouUnder = Chikou < close
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbLLM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the line specifically, the variable you're plotting is `xChikou`, so use that to create your over / under comparison.

Something like:

```
ChikouOver = xChikou > close  // true or false
ChikouUnder = xChikou < close // true or false
```

Or if you wanted over / under the candle bodies, something like:

```
ChikouOver = xChikou > open and open > close // true when over the open and it's a green candle
ChikouUnder = xChikou < close and open < close // true when below the close and it's a red candle
```

You can plot this for debugging in the data window using

```
plot(ChikouOver ? 1 : 0, title="ChikouOver")
plot(ChikouUnder ? 1 : 0, title="ChikouUnder")
```

where 1 = true and 0 = false in the data window

Comment: My xChikou is plotted with an offset which displace it on the graph and i want to declare the displaced xchikou value. Is my xChikou value changing after being plotted or i need to define it by a new declared "xchikoudisplaced" ?

Comment: Each of the variables eg xChikou, close, ChikouOver etc is a series.  xChikou[0] == xChikou (this bars value).  If you want to access a previous value (eg, previous bars value), you can access it with xChikou[1].  If you wanted to access the value 17 bars ago, it would be xChickou[17].  Hope that helps!
On your plot, th xChikou value doesn't change, it's just the plot that's displaced.